# reproduce UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched in UITableViewStylePlain

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can one reproduce the same effect as Single Line Etched when using plain table and custom cells?

I think I need to add them as subview to each cell, excluding the last one. I want to know how to reproduce that without having to use images to that. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the separator just a single pixel grey line, even for Single Line Etched?

In this case, create a UIView the width of the cell, but only one pixel high and then set it's background colour,then stick it at the bottom of the cell's content view.

```
UIView *lineView;

lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                    cell.contentView.bounds.size.height-1.0f,
                                                    cell.contentView.bounds.size.width,
                                                    1.0f);
lineView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

[cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
```

Comment: I think the etched is two lines, with different colors. Isn't too much adding a view just to draw a line?